# Opens the url with image zoomed how to get it normally?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, attachment, inappbrowser

i Have attachment in my application and on clicking the attachment the attachment opens in a in app browser i used this to open
`var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');` whats the problem is this opens a image in fully zoomed so how can i make the image come normally its comming normally in the android app and web app. can any one help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Put the image in a webpage and set your `viewport`.